# Debugging react: breakpoint not stopping in componentDidUpdate as expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm looking at some code on a react/node/prismic application that I've inherited. So far the [intelliJ chrome plugin](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/debugging-javascript-in-chrome.html) has been great for setting breakpoints and seeing what's happening, but I have a case where I can't get it to stop at a breakpoint inside code that I know is executing.

My application uses a ScrollToTop using the component subclass as recommended [here](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/scroll-restoration). See code below.

**I can see the behavior working**: if I load the application, scroll down the page, and hit refresh, the page reloads at the top of the page. So we MUST be hitting that "scrollTo" line in the componentDidUpdate block, right? (we don't do `window.scrollTo(0,0)` in any other code in the application).

BUT, when I run in debug mode with breakpoints, if I put a breakpoint on the scrollTo line and repeat the steps above, we never stop there in the debugger. On the other hand if I put a breakpoint on the render line, we do stop at the breakpoint as expected.

I'm new to react/javascript- is there something weird about componentDidUpdate that would explain this behavior?

thanks in advance!

ScrollToTop.js:

```
import React from 'react'
import { withRouter } from 'react-router'

class ScrollToTop extends React.Component {
    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
        if (this.props.location !== prevProps.location) { 
            window.scrollTo(0, 0) // Breakpoint on this line does nothing
        }
    }

    render() {  // Breakpoint on this line does stop
        return this.props.children
    }
}

export default withRouter(ScrollToTop)
```

Then router.js wraps everything in that ScrollToTop like so:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'
import ScrollToTop from './app/Utils/ScrollToTop'
import routes from './routes'

export default (({prismicCtx, PRISMIC_UNIVERSAL_DATA}) => {
  return (
    <ScrollToTop>
      <Switch>
        {routes(prismicCtx, PRISMIC_UNIVERSAL_DATA).map((route, index) => {
          const copyRoute = Object.assign({}, route)
          if (copyRoute.render) delete copyRoute.component
          return <Route key={`route-${index}`} {...copyRoute} />
        })}
      </Switch>
    </ScrollToTop>
  )
})
```

Answer (score 3):

Just a question first, when you say you hit refresh you are talking about the refresh button in the browser, right ?

If so, **componentDidUpdate** will not be called, the page actually make the initial render when the browser ask for it on refresh.

`componentDidUpdate() is invoked immediately after updating occurs. This method is not called for the initial render.`

Comment: Ah yes you're totally right! Reloading the browser would just be another call to render(). I'm looking into a new bug (comparing this working branch to the new/broken branch) where in that other branch following the same steps causes the refreshed screen to load at the bottom of the page instead of the top. Based on the name "ScrollToTop.js" I've wrongly accused this bit of code! But you're right- the scenario where I scroll and reload is probably something else, like maybe the old location getting stuck?

Comment: If you want to use **scrollTo** in your page you can use **componentDidMount**.

The fact that its not returning to the top is because browsers are like this. You can try this behavior here on stackoverflow where scrolling down and refreshing will re-render the page but will not go back to the top :)

Comment: oh you're right- I never noticed that before. I wonder how my existing/live application has different behavior (it scrolls to the top)- I guess the new branch is doing something more expected. I'll have a closer look at the rest of the code. Thank you!